# Angular 2: Setting values from http get into Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I'm trying to set a variable inside my Angular service to make it available for my components.

> quotation.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { SupplyersList } from '../pages/comparative-map/interfaces/comparative-map.interfaces';

@Injectable()
export class QuotationService {
    baseUrl: string;
    supplyers_list: SupplyersList[];

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('%c ▸QuotationService Initialized...', 'color:#0098f1');
        this.baseUrl = 'http://104.197.212.14:3000';
        this.quotationId = 10;

        this.getQuotationSupplyers().subscribe(supplyers => {
            this.supplyers_list = supplyers;
        });

    }
    getQuotationSupplyers() {
        // return this.http.get('/app/data/quotation_supliers.data.json').map(res => res.json());
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl  + '/providers?id=' + this.quotationId, this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

    // private helper methods
    private jwt() {
        // create authorization header with jwt token
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            let headers = new Headers({ 'x-access-token': currentUser.token });
            return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        }
    }
}
```

> comparative-map.interfaces

```
export interface SupplyersList {
  name: string;
  logo: string;
  id: number;
  position: number;
  destination_distance: number;
  itens: SupplyersItens[];
  checked: boolean;
}
```

> comparative-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { QuotationService } from '../../../../services/quotation.service';
import { QuotationItens } from '../../interfaces/comparative-map.interfaces';
import { BestPrice } from '../../interfaces/comparative-map.interfaces';
import { SupplyersList } from '../../interfaces/comparative-map.interfaces';
import { SupplyersItens } from '../../interfaces/comparative-map.interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'comparative-details',
  templateUrl: './comparative-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comparative-details.component.css']
})
export class ComparativeMapDetailsComponent {

  /** quotation data */
  @Input('quotationItens')
  quotation_itens: QuotationItens[];
  @Input('destinationName')
  destination_name: string;
  supplyers_list: SupplyersList[];

  constructor(private QuotationService: QuotationService) {

    this.supplyers_list = this.QuotationService.supplyers_list;

  }

  setSelectedSupplyer(event: any) {
    const supplyer_id = Number(event.target.value);

    this.supplyers_list.forEach(function(supplyer){
      if (supplyer.id !== supplyer_id) {
        supplyer.checked = false;
      }
    });
    this.QuotationService.setSelectedSupplyer(event);
  }
}
```

[image]

When I try to access suppliers_list from QuotationService I get this:

[image]

I'm trying to make this available for all the application

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: whats the issue 
?

Comment: I'm trying to make this HTTP return available for all my application into QuotationService.supplyers_list

Comment: you need to make the supplyers_list as a subject, which you can subscribe in your component. if you want to supplyers_list then first initialise them with empty array.

Comment: please check http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject . using `Subject` and subscribing for that subject in component will do the trick

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'll try later and come back with feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Ankit Rana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4877428/ankit-rana) and [@Rahul Naik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1608841/rahul-naik) I've found out that I needed to set supplyers_list as `Subject`

Update above:

> quotation.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { SupplyersList } from '../pages/comparative-map/interfaces/comparative-map.interfaces';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class QuotationService {
    baseUrl: string;
    private supplyers_list = new Subject<any>();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('%c ▸QuotationService Initialized...', 'color:#0098f1');
        this.baseUrl = 'http://104.197.212.14:3000';
        this.quotationId = 10;

        this.getQuotationSupplyers().subscribe(supplyers => {
            this.supplyers_list = supplyers;
        });

    }

    returnAvailableSupplyersList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.available_supplyers.asObservable();
    }

    getQuotationSupplyers() {
        // return this.http.get('/app/data/quotation_supliers.data.json').map(res => res.json());
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl  + '/providers?id=' + this.quotationId, this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

    // private helper methods
    private jwt() {
        // create authorization header with jwt token
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            let headers = new Headers({ 'x-access-token': currentUser.token });
            return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        }
    }
}
```

> comparative-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { QuotationService } from '../../../../services/quotation.service';
import { QuotationItens, BestPrice , SupplyersList, SupplyersItens  } from '../../interfaces/comparative-map.interfaces';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'comparative-details',
  templateUrl: './comparative-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comparative-details.component.css']
})
export class ComparativeMapDetailsComponent {

  /** quotation data */
  @Input('quotationItens')
  quotation_itens: QuotationItens[];
  @Input('destinationName')
  destination_name: string;
  supplyers_list: SupplyersList[];

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private QuotationService: QuotationService) {

      this.subscription =  this.QuotationService.returnQuotationSupplyers().subscribe(supplyers => {
          this.supplyers_list = supplyers;
      });

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  setSelectedSupplyer(event: any) {
    const supplyer_id = Number(event.target.value);

    this.supplyers_list.forEach(function(supplyer){
      if (supplyer.id !== supplyer_id) {
        supplyer.checked = false;
      }
    });
    this.QuotationService.setSelectedSupplyer(event);
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot, guys. It saved-me

Answer (score -2):

Angular 2 is type script, that similar to object oriented language.

In the component, you can call this method as below.

```
this.QuotationService.getQuotationSupplyers(quotationId);
```

Comment: Methods are public by default in TypeScript.

Comment: Yep. They are public by default in Typescript as @NikolajDamLarsen mentioned